# Cannot show local images

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT and I am using Image Widget to view an image. This image is located in my file system.

I wrote the following line of code:

```
String src = "file:///D:/myfolder/myfile.jpg";
Image image = new Image();
image.setUrl(src);
```

Please note I need to show only local images; not from the server. It may sound strange but I need to show from the client machine. Assume all clients will have same image and same path.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that what are you trying is not possible due to "Same Origin Policy" in browsers:  [Same Origin Policy Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: just try this html it is working.<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>


 
 <img id = "img1" src="#" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; "/>
 <input type="button" onclick="getElementById('img1').src = 'file:///C:/PROJECTS/bmis/com.sflpro.bmis.ui/com.sflpro.bmis.ui/bin/Debug/RD/2011/11/18/2011_11_18_47262195/Photo.jpg'" />
 

</body>
</html>

Comment: It is working, because you have opened your test HTML file for local drive and it is applied different restrictions. Try to upload it to Web server and open via `http://` protocol.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Try to explore workarounds for Same Origin Policy, there might be some.

Or just rework your logic.

Comment: Actually I am not trying to access local file I am just instructing browser to show that file in his layout. do you have some link where I can read about that security issue? it's interesting.

Comment: It will work if the user have selected file via <input type="file"> but that's the only case. Modern browsers don't allow to embed local resources into remote web-pages because of security issues

Comment: This is the intended way of things, not an issue. Other then Wikipedia you should try searching for ways to get around Same Origin Policy (if possible at all), or just rework your logic.

For example, you could introduce database in your application, and then each user would have to upload an image on first log in, and when the time comes to serve the image you would get it from the database, not from a local file system.

Comment: The thing is a little bit complicated in my case. I have .Net WinForms application which contains in it Chromium Browser. so In chromium Browser the GWT application is loaded. From Host(WinForms) application working with some scanner and scanning images in local folder. I need to show scanned images in my GWT application. I found the way passing the scanned image path to the GWT application via calling some public JavaScript method.The think is I cannot show it. I think only solution remains is passing Image content to that Javascript as BASE64 and show it if yoiu have any other ideas welcome.

Answer (score -1):

It's very unusual that you have to specify full path with drive name.
There are many ways to get your context path and then make the path relative to it.

I've just tried to setUrl to the GWT's Image in your way. Everything was fine.
Try to check your path, image extension etc.

Maybe your do something wrong when add image to the layout?

Comment: you cannot use relative paths here the I want to show image from client pc. in this case have to specify full path.

Comment: Javascript has no access to your local files.

But you can still try to add "file:///*/*" in your manifest file in permissions section.

P.S. GWT's look on security issue. [link](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_Server.html#What_is_the_Same_Origin_Policy,_and_how_does_it_affect_GWT?)